# django - model form with 'helper select'

Tags: django-forms

I'm looking for best solution for this issue:

I'have a Model like this:

```
class annotation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, ... )
    annotation =  models.TextField( ...
```

A form for this Model may be:

```
product: [ a select to chose a product ]
annotations: [ a input type text ]
```

But, because product table is big, I show a previous select to user:

```
product family: [ a select to chose a product family ]
product: [ a select to chose a product in selected product family ]
annotations: [ a input type text ]
```

(Product family is another model and product has a foreign key to it)

My first solution was to write a new widget called SelectAjax and use it on ModelChoiceField. It works fine, but is not an elegant solution for me.

Can someone propose an alternative?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm also interested

Comment: Only commented solution, the 'SelectAjax' widget. It works, but I'm interested in some more standard solution.

Comment: I'm also searching for a standard way to do that, so therefore in the interim I'm using [filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)